# Using BuildKit with a mounted `/var/run/docker.sock` in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker, docker-buildkit

I have a registered `gitlab-runner` with a `docker` executor. When it runs this `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: "1" 

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # There are additional flags cut out requiring BuildKit.
    - docker build .
```

and `/var/run/docker.sock` mounted, it fails with:

```
ERROR: docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental not found
------
 > resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: docker.io/docker/dockerfile:experimental not found
```

When I include

```
services:
  - docker:dind
```

to `.gitlab-ci.yml` and remove the `/var/run/docker.sock` mount (so changing the daemon used to being the child container's instead of the host's), it succeeds.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
...
```

Is there an incompatibility with BuildKit / experiment syntax and using the host's docker socket? I have it working with the child container using its own socket through `dind`, but I want to have this succeed with the socket mounted instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by following the solution at [BuildKit mode fails to fetch the frontend image when `registry-mirrors` is specified](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39120#issuecomment-562587888). Thing is there were no registry mirrors for my `gitlab-runner`, but doing the following before the job executed did the trick:

```
docker pull docker/dockerfile:experimental 

# Replace with whatever image `Dockerfile` is based on.
docker pull ubuntu:latest
```

Still in the dark as to why this issue relates to the `registry-mirrors` one and is fixed by the same thing, but for now this does the job.